# List of records per date

Tags: mysql, date, optimization

I am trying to get records as per the following query :-

```
select distinct type, count(type), created_at from study_aids where date(created_at) = '2015-09-02' 
GROUP BY type
```

and i get the the result in following manner

```
type           count(type)            created_at
FlashCardDeck   752                 2015-09-02T15:29:34.000Z
MindMap         6692                2015-09-02T13:52:38.000Z
```

I need to manually go and replace date,whereas i need the query which displays results as per next dates in following way autmoatically :-

```
type           count(type)            created_at
FlashCardDeck   752                 2015-09-02T15:29:34.000Z
MindMap         6692                2015-09-02T13:52:38.000Z
XYZ           1234                   ****2015-09-03T13:52:38.000**Z**
```

PS - i don't need the sum, i need the count of each type of records for a particular date.

Thanks

Comment: Is count returns the sum??

Comment: Remove the created_at column from your query and drop the distinct. Is this sql server or mysql? They are not the same thing and handle dates a little differently.

Comment: @SeanLange This is MySQL

Comment: In addition to what @SeanLange pointed out, YOu should consider changes your WHERE clause to something like `WHERE created BETWEEN '2015-09-02 00:00:00' AND '2015-09-02 23:59:59'` This will allow you to make use of index on `created_at` where as comparing against calculated value as done using `DATE()` would disallow use of index.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai - No count doesn't returns the sum. Just the no of records for a particular date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guessing this must be mysql. The query including the date of created_at would be something like this.

```
select type
    , count(type)
    , date(created_at)
from study_aids 
where created_at >= '2015-09-02' 
AND created_at < '2015-09-03'
GROUP BY type
    , date(created_at)
```

Comment: Yes, this works for me and gives me the results as expected. Thanks a mil for the same :)